# Redirecting Ambari-Server backup file creation to a different location

Tags: backup, hadoop

I am taking backup of my Ambari server using the command

```
ambari-server backup
```

This creates the backup file in the location */var/lib/ambari-server/*

I want the backup to go to a different location, and I am not finding the way to do it. The help option of the `ambari-server` command is not helping much. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the command is as simple as

```
ambari-server backup /path/where/you/want/backup/file/to/go/
```